# Regroup pair of nodes in a template

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have an XML file that contains a list of events. Each event is, in fact, a `begin` and an `end` event of a period. Suppose the following XML :

```
<Events>
    <Event id="1" type="begin" date="xxxx"/>
    <Event id="2" type="end" date="xxxy"/>
    <Event id="3" type="begin" date="xxyx"/>
    <Event id="4" type="end" date="xyxx"/>
    <Event id="5" type="begin" date="yxxx"/>
    <Event id="6" type="end" date="xxyy"/>
</Events>
```

What I want to apply is something looking like this :

```
<Events>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//Event"/>
</Events>

<xsl:template match="Event">
    <Period>
        <Begin>
            <Event>
                <xsl:attribute name="id" select="[@type='begin']/@id"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="date" select="[@type='begin']/@date"/>
            </Event>
        </Begin>
        <End>
            <Event>
                <xsl:attribute name="id" select="[@type='end']/@id"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="date" select="[@type='end']/@date"/>
            </Event>
        </End>
    </Period>
</xsl:template>
```

And the expected result would be this :

```
<Events>
    <Period>
        <Begin>
            <Event id="1" type="begin" date="xxxx"/>
        </Begin>

        <End>
            <Event id="2" type="end" date="xxxy"/>
        </End>
    </Period>

    <Period>
        <Begin>
            <Event id="3" type="begin" date="xxyx"/>
        </Begin>

        <End>
            <Event id="4" type="end" date="xyxx"/>
        </End>
    </Period>

    <Period>
        <Begin>
            <Event id="5" type="begin" date="yxxx"/>
        </Begin>

        <End>
            <Event id="6" type="end" date="xxyy"/>
        </End>
    </Period>
</Events>
```

But the result is this one :

```
<Events>
    <Period>
        <Begin>
            <Event id="1" type="begin" date="xxxx"/>
        </Begin>

        <End>
            <Event id="" type="end" date=""/>
        </End>
    </Period>

    <Period>
        <Begin>
            <Event id="" type="begin" date=""/>
        </Begin>

        <End>
            <Event id="2" type="end" date="xxxy"/>
        </End>
    </Period>

    ...

</Events>
```

I understand why I got this result, since the template matches elements by elements one after the other, but I want to know if there is a way to achieve my goal by using a template matching "two nodes at the same time" ? I've looked over SO but the only thing that I found which is near the solution I want is the Muenchian grouping (which seems really complicated to setup for a small dataset like the one above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, something like this should do the job - I am assuming that the `<Event type="begin">` is always immediately followed by its corresponding `<Event type="end">`.

```
<xsl:template match="Event[@type='begin']">
    <Period>
        <Begin>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </Begin>
        <End>
            <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::Event[1]"/>
        </End>
    </Period>
</xsl:template>
```

Demo here : http://xsltransform.net/ejivdH4

Comment: If your template matches the event with `[@type='begin']` how come the following-sibling is the `end` type ? Shouldn't you match every `Event` ?

Comment: Because I select and perform an exact copy of the `Event[@type='end']` explicitely. In this case I don't need a "match" to process the `Event` - even more, I need to avoid matching these element in the transformation process.

Comment: Okay I understood. Thank you very much for your answer, the `following-sibling` is what was missing in my case and it did the trick. Again, thank you !